# Ruby yard: ENV['FOO'] without link

Tags: ruby, yard

I write a document with yard.

I want to write environment variables as is.

```
# ENV['FOO']
```

I expect this to ENV['FOO'] or `ENV['FOO']`. But this becomes a link like this with `yard server`.

```
[ENV](http://localhost:8808/docs/MyModule/'FOO')
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: Put it into backticks: `\`ENV['FOO']\``. It will both prevent autolinkage and make is of fixed width.

Comment: backticks do not work with ENV. `\`ENV['foo']\`` shows `\`ENV\`` and does autolink.

Comment: Ran into this problem for the first time today. It is still an issue. Backticks still don't work. It took a lot of creative googling to find this question with no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this

```
ENV !{'FOO'}
```

which rendered as

> ENV {'FOO'}

Not idea, but better than a link.